# Клики внутри и вне блока

Tags: javascript, click, mouse-event

У меня есть расширение которое я пишу для google chrome, оно будет выполнять некоторые операции с субтитрами. Вообщем блок с видео я определяю вот так:

```
let video = document.getElementsByTagName('video');
let coor = video[0].getBoundingClientRect();
videoC.x_start = coor.left;
videoC.x_end = coor.right;
videoC.y_start = coor.top;
videoC.y_end = coor.bottom - 40;
```

Тут вроде вполне понятно, я определяю координаты блока, относительно страницы.

Дальше у меня на клики повешаны события, но проблема в том, что клик возвращает координаты только относительно окна и получается если я кликаю под видео, он определяет что я кликаю на видео, а это не есть хорошо. Сравнения я провожу так:

```
if (subtitle) {
    text_subtitle = e.path[0].innerText;
    if (((videoC.x_start <= e.left) && (e.left <= videoC.x_end)) && ((videoC.y_start <= e.top) && (e.top <= videoC.y_end))) {
        console.log('Нажатие на субтитры');
        innerTranslateObject(document.caretRangeFromPoint(e.x, e.y), user, e.pageY, subtitle, text_subtitle);
    }
} else {
    if (((videoC.x_start > e.x) && (e.x > videoC.x_end)) && ((videoC.y_start > e.y) && (e.y > videoC.y_end))) {
        console.log('Нажатие на обычные слова вне субтитров');
        innerTranslateObject(document.caretRangeFromPoint(e.x, e.y), user, e.pageY, subtitle, text_subtitle);
    }
}
```

Ну вообщем как мне поправить чтобы у меня клик в не блока видео можно было определить.
Весь код прикладывать не буду т.к. там 400+ строк.

Ах да вот как я слушаю клик:

```
if ((video.length > 0) && subtitleTranslate) {
    document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        createAndSendData(e, true);
    });
}
```

Comment: Я может не совсем понимаю вашу проблему, но в моих задачах мне помогал код типа такого:
    document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
       e.target.className === "test" ? console.log("yes") : console.log("no")
    });

Это если мне надо проверить кликнули на элемент с классом test или нет.

Comment: можно вешать слушатели на разные элементы документа

Comment: Ну вы же не на само видео событие повесели, а на весь документ, то есть в e.target вы получите элемент на странице по которому кликнули

Comment: Вы все не поняли, у меня расширение для браузера, стало быть я буду взаимодействовать со страницами через js, и соответственно методы через
классы мне не подойдут, поэтому я решил, что координаты самый оптимальный вариант, т.к. очень универсальный

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кажется я нашел ответ на свой вопрос, выглядит он так:

```
if (subtitle) {
    text_subtitle = e.path[0].innerText;
    if (((videoC.x_start <= e.pageX) && (e.pageX <= videoC.x_end)) && ((videoC.y_start <= e.pageY) && (e.pageY <= videoC.y_end))) {
        console.log('Нажатие на субтитры');
        innerTranslateObject(document.caretRangeFromPoint(e.x, e.y), user, e.pageY, subtitle, text_subtitle);
    }
} else {
    if (((videoC.x_start <= e.pageX) && (e.pageX <= videoC.x_end)) && ((videoC.y_start <= e.pageY) && (e.pageY <= videoC.y_end))) {
    } else {
        console.log('Нажатие на обычные слова вне субтитров');
        innerTranslateObject(document.caretRangeFromPoint(e.x, e.y), user, e.pageY, subtitle, text_subtitle);
    }
}
```

Кароче если в вкратце `e.pageX` и `e.pageY` отдают координаты относительно страницы, что вообщем мне и нужно было.